# How to change button color depending on array element in ReactJS

Tags: css, arrays, reactjs

Say I have two arrays like this:

```
state = {
   firstArr: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
   secondArr: ['one', 'three', 'four']
}
```

and I'm having a list of buttons like below:

```
{firstArray.map((item, index) => (
    <label className="btn btn-secondary" key={index}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleAddItem} value={item} /> {item}                              
    </label>
))}
```

How do I apply a different background color only to the buttons listed in the second array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a conditional class like this, based on whether the current item is part of `secondArr` or not.

```
{firstArray.map((item, index) => (
    <label
        className={`btn btn-secondary ${secondArr.includes(item) ? 'different-bg-class' : ''}`}
        key={index}
    >
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleAddItem} value={item} /> {item}                              
    </label>
))}
```